# Compiling using g++ error: virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: gcc, compilation, garbage-collection, g++, out-of-memory

I'm compiling some software (nodejs, in this case) in a system with very limited memory (around 800mb usable) and the compilation is failing partway through due to hitting this memory limit, with the error message `virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory`.

Upgrading the system's memory is not an option, and I just need to be able to compile this software once on it.

Comment: Disabling optimization is likely to help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution enabling me to continue the compilation, as initially mentioned [on the debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceBuildMemoryOverhead), passing g++ the flag `--param ggc-min-expand=10` reduces its memory use, specifically by forcing gcc's garbage collector to run more often, as documented in [the gcc optimization docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

before re-running make, simply run
`export CXXFLAGS="--param ggc-min-expand=10"` (or `export CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS --param ggc-min-expand=10"` to preserve any existing options you've set with the CXXFLAGS) to set that parameter on all invocations of g++ needed for the compilation.

You can potentially set the min-expand value even lower than 10 if needed, but it may further decrease the compilation speed, and it wasn't necessary in my case.